# Showing PDF in a browser and getting the Text selected by the user (flash will do as well)

Tags: asp.net, flash, apache-flex, pdf

I want to show a PDF in browser, from which user can select text, showing pdf is very easy i have done this using "pdfviewer" control, now i want to get the selected text which the user selects in the PDF, is there any way to achieve this? i am using asp.net.

Edit: If there is a flash/ flex solution at the client end that will as well, does anyone know about it, i tried one API, but that dint seem to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a JavaScript PDF action to the page and have it post to an online form.

Comment: could you please explain it, how to achieve this?

Comment: I did not read your question correctly. I was under the impression that the your PDF was getting displayed by Adobe Reader plugin. Adobe Reader has a Javascript interpreter and the PDF document could be programmed to http post text selections. But you seem to using some PDF Viewer control. This control may not support PDF Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

[The PDF Viewer control from Winnovative doesn't offer any text selection APIs at all](http://www.winnovative-software.com/Doc/HTML/PdfViewerAspNet/Pdf%20Viewer%20for%20ASP.NET.html).

Acrobat's JavaScript engine doesn't either.

Sorry: No.